# django template datetime filter displays month instead of minute

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

what should the following look like?

```
{% now "YmdHMS" %}
```

according to python...

```
>>> import datetime
>>> datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d%H%M%S")
'20140227121922'
```

but in my template, the result is...

2014022712Febth

How can I make this work properly?

Comment: can you try the official documentation from Django https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#date

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
{% now "YmdHis" %}
```

Here is a table with datetime format strings:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#date

You should take a look at those docs:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#now
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/i18n/formatting/#format-localization

Answer (score 0):

Just figured out that I'd make a function on the view to do this (because outside of the template the date string formats correctly). I'd still love to know why it doesn't work in the template...

Answer (score 0):

`{% now "YmdHis" %}`

django templatetag filtering of datetime is different from python `strftime()`

Answer (score 0):

complete date and time

{{ created_at|date:"Y-m-d H:i" }}

only time

{{ created_at|date:"H:i" }}

hours and minutes after the post created_at

{{ created_at|timesince }}

date and month

{{ created_at|date:"jS \o\f F"}}

Comment: instead you can use: {{ value|date:"D d M Y" }} or/and {{ value|time:"H:i" }}

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/